# Audio shorts to floats

Tags: android, audio

A YIN pitch detection algorithm has been implemented using JDK ~6 & requires sampling an array of floats.

I would like to implement the pitch detection on Android API 10 which does not have the javax.sound.sampled package YIN uses. API 10 does have RecordAudio which can deliver either bytes or shorts with read(byte/short[] int pos, int size).

What would optimize performance?
A) to extend Android 1.5's RecordAudio to get a floats to YIN (my preferred method) *or*
B) to take the shorts from RecordAudio, convert them to floats, and then pass these to the YIN input buffer.

In either case, I don't know the appropriate way to get the shorts
(44100, PCM16, signed, mono, littleEndian) to floats.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the algorithm you need in [this](https://java.net/projects/gervill/sources/Mercurial/content/src/com/sun/media/sound/AudioFloatConverter.java) class.

https://java.net/projects/gervill/sources/Mercurial/content/src/com/sun/media/sound/AudioFloatConverter.java

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
f = (float) (short) (((short)wavData[i] & 0xFF) + (((short)wavData[i+1] & 0xFF) << 8));
```

where `wavData` is just an array of raw bytes, as read from a wave file.

It should work for all samplerates, any channel count (mono and stereo). It works only for 16 bit PCM, which by the way is usually signed, but it can be extended for larger resolutions.

Comment: I found something similar in the answer above yours...                                    out_buff[ox] = (short)(in_buff[ix++] & 0xff | in_buff[ix++] << 8) * 3.051851E-05F; It's been a long time since I've been down in the bits so I assume for the moment these are identical with the exception of the *3-05F

Comment: the 3e-05 is 1.0/(2^(16-1)) and is to scale the floating point samples to the range of -1.0 to 1.0.